# JavaScript: Get days difference between MySQL Timestamp and Current date?

Tags: javascript

JavaScript prints out MySQL timestamp as: "2015-01-04T16:59:33.000Z" for me,
How can I get difference in days between that date and today?

It should return 56 Days Difference, is there any simple way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = new Date("2015-01-04T16:59:33.000Z");
var b = Date.parse(a);
var c = Date.parse(new Date().toISOString()); //use toISOString to return UTC date.


var diff = c - b;
var diffInDays = diff/1000/60/60/24;
document.body.textContent = diffInDays; //just to show output in the snippet.
```

This will convert the date from now and the date your SQL supplied to milliseconds and subtracts them from each other.

Since they are milliseconds, divide by 1000 milliseconds, than 60 seconds, 60 minutes and 24 hours to get the days.

Comment: Was going to upvote, but that `document.write` is unacceptable.

Comment: @SecondRikudo  document.write is just to show the output in the snippet.

Comment: `document.write` is a cancer upon JavaScript. By placing it in an example, you're promoting it as a legitimate tool.

Comment: This worked great with slight modification. 
It returns 55.6 or so in decimals, so I will just round that off and return as value.

Comment: @SecondRikudo, you have a valid point, edited it to avoid the dreaded `document.write` that breaks so many things.

Comment: Thank you! I made an edit to make it slightly cleaner :)

Comment: @SecondRikudo I agree with you about the document.write part, many who come across this post may be mis-lead by it in future. The solution is good though.

Comment: @arleitiss If this solution solved your problem, don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: @SecondRikudo yes, was waiting for timer of SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Moment.js](http://www.momentjs.com) for sane date handling in Javascript.

```
moment().diff(moment('2015-01-04T16:59:33.000Z'), 'days')
```

The above accounts for your current timezone. You could also use

```
moment.utc().diff(moment('2015-01-04T16:59:33.000Z'), 'days')
```